# Symfony Twig For Loop

Tags: php, symfony

Hi I have a three column layout like the following:

```
<div class="container">
 <div id="col1">
 </div>
 <div id="col2">
 </div>
 <div id="col3">
 </div>
<div>
```

So I have data that I want to fill in the columns using a the for loop in twig. I couldn't think of a way to do this except to pass the data for each column into an array for each column in the controller and pass it to the view then loop though each array.

I'm relativly new to both PHP and Symfony and I think I am over/under thinking this. I don't want anyone to do the work for me , just an idea in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: can you give an example output?

Answer (score 0):

What you said is the best practise for this. But instead of the second array, an object is usually used.

I don't know what data your are talking about and how you get that data. But it is likely that you get those from a database. Did you read the [Doctrine article in the book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html)? They show you how you can handle things like this.

Comment: Yes I'm getting the data from an db and I'm still wrapping my head around Doctrine. Yes I've created an object and it is returning an array f objects, I guess getting everything into the correct columns once the data is passed to the view is where I'm getting confused on.    Thanks for your response!

Comment: @wali you know you can access object properties like `myobject.name`? What is confusing for you? If you can explain that, we can help them.

Comment: Actually I'm getting the data from a json source now...so Doctrine isn't useful now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess the data is split between columns following conditions. You should try to apply those conditions in your controller and send 3 arrays to twig.
It would help if you explained more (maybe with some code) about the db and the query.